# Simulate Input text in a field with new line

Tags: java, html, web

I add a text in a field of a contact form with this script

`document.getElementById('IDtextarea').value = 'Hello ¶ Would you';`

I don't know how simulate new line ? How can I do it ?

Comment: Why use `¶` at all? The `textarea` should preserve the line separators while sending it to server (browser may ignore them while presenting it, but they will be there). For now this looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: the software I use, to generate text with new line you need to use ¶, then that generated text is used to generate a javascript

Answer (score 0):

Find out, replace "¶" by "\n"